# 14.04.2: gave up waiting on root device

Tags: boot, grub2, initramfs

I've just installed `14.04.2`, and after selecting `Ubuntu` in `grub` I get dumped to an `initramfs` shell. The error reads `gave up waiting on root device`.

The device it's trying to mount by `UUID`, hosting the root file-system, is the right one. It's hosted in the first partition of an `SSD` drive. This setup worked fine with my previous installation.

However, now the disk is not detected. The output of `blkid` from this shell **is empty**. The drive should be in `/dev/sdb`, but **the file doesn't exist**. `/dev/sda` (my other drive) isn't listed either.

What's going on?

Comment: Are you using disk encryption?

Comment: No, no encryption

Answer (score 0):

"add rootdelay=90 to the kernel stanza for your current kernel"

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IntrepidReleaseNotes#Boot%20failures%20on%20systems%20with%20Intel%20D945%20motherboards

Comment: I'm already waiting around 20 seconds. What would I be waiting to for?

Comment: According to this, it's because the SSD modules aren't yet loaded:

[udevadm trigger](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=752591#5)